# React / Javascript - how to filter data received to a filtered list of columns?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I receive data / an array with objects. each object has country - city and shops (in that city).

For example:

1. USA - Los Angeles - shop1
2. Italy - Milan - shop2
3. Italy - Rome - shopXY

   ```
   var data = [
     {country: "Italy", city: "Milan", shop: "shop123"},
     {country: "Italy", city: "Rome", shop: "shop2"},
     {country: "USA", city: "Los Angeles", shop: "shopXY"}
   ]
   ```

I have 3 columns and I want to show only once Italy, then when I click on it, I show Milan and Rome, then based on whether I click Rome or Milan the corresponding shops.

Would it be good practise to:

1. get all the data, then create a new array of objects, so I dont have duplicate countries, cities etc.
2. Use filter method- but how could I filter it, how can check for duplicates 
   without storing them in a new array or the like?
3. Anything else?

I tried to research but couldn't really find anything and even if someone just has some tips, it would be great as I'm totally lost. Thanks!!!!

PS. I don't want to use any filter libraries for that as I m trying to do it myself.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40774906/128165

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MTTI answers is good, and to get to it, I'd use a reduce

```
const newData = data.reduce((acc, val) => {
  if (!acc[val.country]) {
    acc[val.country] = { [val.city]: [val.shop] };
    return acc;
  }
  if (!acc[val.country][val.city]) {
    acc[val.country][val.city] = [val.shop];
    return acc;
  }
  acc[val.country][val.city].push(val.shop);
  return acc;
}, {})
```

So in the end you'll get an object like

```
{
  Italy: {
    Rome: ['Shop123'],
    Milan: ['Shop12']
  },
  USA: {
    "San Francisco": ['Shop420']
  }
}
```

Comment: Just one additional question: Would it be possible to sort the countries based on how many cities it got? So if a country has 10 cities listed and another one less, the first one comes first? because it has to be an object, not an array, but its not possible to sort an object

Comment: @javascripting You can add a property to each country called length, increase the size of this property everytime you put a new shop on that country, then convert the object to an array using a for loop, or `Object.keys(newData)`

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend using a javascript object, as opposed to making a new array, with the processed data. 
The property/value semantics of a Javascript object have following advantages

1.) **Duplicates are automatically taken care of**: Using the country as a key, you either create a new sub-object mapping shops to cities, or you simply expand an already present one

2.) **Ease of access**: Finding a Country/shop becomes as simple as `data['Italy']['Rome']`

Seems like a perfect fit for your use-case. The static way of defining such an object, in adherence to your example woud be:

```
var data = {
  "Italy": {
    "Milan": ["shop123"],
    "Rome": ["shop2"]
  },
  "USA": {
    "Los Angeles": ["shopXY"]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd just edit the values on the cities to being an array, instead of a string, as there might be more than 1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following script to filter the data after that you can iterate on the result of the script to show the data as you want.

```
   var data = [{
        country: "Italy",
        city: "Milan",
        shop: "shop123"
    },
    {
        country: "Italy",
        city: "Rome",
        shop: "shop2"
    },
    {
        country: "USA",
        city: "Los Angeles",
        shop: "shopXY"
    },
]

var result = {};
data.forEach(function (item) {
    if (result[item.country]) {
        result[item.country][item.city] = item.shop
    } else {
        result[item.country] = {};
        result[item.country][item.city] = item.shop
    }
});
```

The out put will be like -

```
{
  "Italy": {
    "Milan": "shop123",
    "Rome": "shop2"
  },
  "USA": {
    "Los Angeles": "shopXY"
  }
}
```